# C# - Using subclasses to implement interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have the following interfaces

```cs
    public interface IPrice
    {
        int Price { get; }
    }

    public interface IGear : IPrice
    {
        GearUpgrade Upgrades { get; }
    }
```

and the following classes

```cs
    public class GearUpgrade : IPrice
    {
        public int Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }

        }
    }

    public class ArmorUpgrade : GearUpgrade
    {
    }

    public class ShieldUpgrade : GearUpgrade
    {
    }

    public class WeaponUpgrade : GearUpgrade
    {
    }
```

So when I try to implement an IGear like this...

```cs
    public class Armor : IGear
    {
        private int price = 0;
        public int Price { get => price; }

        private ArmorUpgrade upgrades;
        public ArmorUpgrade Upgrades
        {
            get { return upgrades; }
            set { upgrades = value; }
        }

    }
```

I get the following error:

> 'Armor' does not implement interface member 'IGear.Upgrades'. 'Armor.Upgrades' cannot implement 'IGear.Upgrades' because it does not have the matching return type of 'GearUpgrade'.

I figured that if `Upgrades` is from a subclass of `GearUpgrade`, the interface should be fulfilled, but apparently it is not... Did I make a false assumption?

Comment: It looks like you want `IGear` to be generic.

Comment: Not sure what would you say that. I have a class `Armor`, `Weapon` and `Shield`. I figured interfaces would be a good abstraction for it. Would you recommend me another implementation, and its advantages?

Comment: This might be because of the example used not being real code, but in case it is: a gear certainly *isn't a* price, in any case, a gear *has a* price

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent because it looks like what you are asking for as code in the question shows *different* return types... which can be perfectly done with generics. Indeed it is very unlikely *useful* to whatever you actually trying to achieve, but that is not in the question at all.

Comment: for those who care, this problem is because c# doesn't have covariant return types. There is a proposal to add that here https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/01/CSharp-Covariant-Return-Types/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to implement the interface, the method signatures have to match exactly: C# doesn't apply covariance and contravariance implicitly.

Here's a simple fix to allow `Armor` to implement the `IGear` interface without messing with the class:

```
public class Armor : IGear
{
    private int price = 0;
    public int Price { get => price; }

    private ArmorUpgrade upgrades;
    public ArmorUpgrade Upgrades
    {
        get { return upgrades; }
        set { upgrades = value; }
    }

    GearUpgrade IGear.Upgrades => this.Upgrades;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This solution seems the more elegant.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Well generic would be much more elegant

Comment: @Franck: That probably depends on how much you know about your `IGear` when you're trying to use it. If all you know is that it's "Gear", then you probably aren't going to be casting it as `IGear<ArmorUpgrade>`: at that point you're just as well casting it to `Armor`.